# Java Copy constructors with generics

Tags: java, generics

This has probably been asked a million times before, but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around writing a copy constructor on an abstract class with a bounded type parameter. I have some code that looks like this:

```
public abstract class Superclass<T> {
    Set<? extends Variable<T>> vars;

    public abstract Superclass<? extends T> copy();

    class Variable<T> {
        T value;
    }
}

class Foo extends Superclass<Integer> {
    public Foo copy() {
        Foo _newFoo = Foo();
        Set<FooVariable> _newVars = new HashSet<FooVariable>();
        _newVars.addAll(this.vars);
        _newFoo.vars = _newVars;
    }

    class FooVariable extends Variable<Integer> { /* ... */ }
}

class Bar extends Superclass<String> {
    public Bar copy() {
        Bar _newBar = Bar();
        Set<BarVariable> _newVars = new HashSet<BarVariable>();
        _newVars.addAll(this.vars);
        _newBar.vars = _newVars;
    }

    class BarVariable extends Variable<String> { /* ... */ }
}
```

Since the `copy` method for both `Foo` and `Bar` is the same except for the variable types, I'd like to be able to move that code into a concrete method in the superclass. But I can't figure out (a) how to have the concrete `public Superclass<? extends T> copy` method return a `Foo` instance if called on a `Foo` and a `Bar` instance if called on a `Bar` and (b) populate the `vars` set with `FooVariable`s or `BarVariable`s as appropriate.

Can anybody please help and tell me what I'm missing? Thanks.

Comment: A copy constructor is an actual constructor that accepts an instance of the class as an argument. This is more of a copy method.

Comment: wont this give compile error on these `Foo _newFoo = Foo();` and what about the missing return type ? Or I am completely misreading some concept

Answer (score 2):

What about this kind of `Superclass`?

```
public abstract class Superclass<T> {

    Set<? extends Variable<T>> vars;

    public Superclass<? extends T> copy() {
        Superclass<T> _newSuperclass = this.getNewInstance();
        Set<Variable<T>> _newVars = new HashSet<Variable<T>>();
        _newVars.addAll(this.vars);
        _newSuperclass.vars = _newVars;
        return _newSuperclass;
    }

    public abstract Superclass<T> getNewInstance();

    class Variable<T> {

        T value;
    }
}
```

The point is that you just need to implement `getNewInstance()` in subclasses instead of constructor.

So `Foo` would look just like:

```
class Foo extends Superclass<Integer> {

    @Override
    public Superclass<Integer> getNewInstance() {
        return new Foo();
    }

    class FooVariable extends Variable<Integer> { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Yes it compiles. Just compiled it with Java 1.7. What should be wrong about that code?

Comment: I think you're missing `_newSuperClass.vars = _newVars;`

Comment: In my mind a copy constructor should create a new and distinct instance of an object, i.e. while a.equals(b) should be true, a == b should be false.  A constructor that merely copies references will not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean for original object `a` and newly created  object `b` for sure holds `a!=b`.  
Maybe you meant "cloning". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a second generic type parameter to represent the `Variable<T>`, `U`.

Then, `Foo.FooVariable<T>` and `Bar.BarVariable<T>` satisfy the bounds of `U` and can be returned from the `copy` method.

**EDIT**

I've changed the code to move the implementation of `copy` into the superclass.  It relies on a `newInstance` method (introduced already by @OndrejBozek).

```
public abstract class Superclass<T, U extends Variable<T>> {
    Set<U> vars;

    class Variable<T> {
        T value;
    }

    public Superclass<T, U> copy() {
        Superclass<T, U> _newSuperclass = newInstance();
        Set<U> _newVars = new HashSet<U>();
        _newVars.addAll(vars);
        _newSuperclass.vars = _newVars;
       return _newSuperclass;
    }

    public abstract Superclass<T, U> newInstance();
}

class Foo extends Superclass<Integer, Foo.FooVariable> {
    public Foo newInstance() { return new Foo(); }

    class FooVariable extends Variable<Integer> { /* ... */ }
}

class Bar extends Superclass<String, Bar.BarVariable> {
    public Bar newInstance() { return new Bar(); }

    class BarVariable extends Variable<String> { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Although this solution does force the type-safety that I'm interested in, I still have pretty much duplicated the code in the `Foo.copy` and `Bar.copy` methods. Can you think of a way to move all of that code into the superclass?

Comment: @jay, I've modified my answer in an attempt to move `copy` into the superclass.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this code, it has a couple of warnings, but it does what you want:

```
public <C extends Superclass<? extends T>> C copy() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    C result= (C) this.getClass().newInstance();
    HashSet newVars= new HashSet();
    newVars.addAll(this.vars);
    result.vars= newVars;
    return result;
}
```

One remark: this is not a copy constructor. This is just a copy method. Constructor does not have a return type and its name is equal to class name.